# Overlay image google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my app I added the map of Google Maps and you can navigate within a given area (which can not be done through maps as it is not drawn). Now I would like to customize the map and add image overlays to the buildings so as to better target people. 
 Let me explain with an example:
[image]
In the picture is the image of the building that I customized.
[image]

Now I want place the image over the google map. I saw that there GroundOverlay but I can not place it properly.

Does anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Polygon Shapes instead of Images. Working with Images like you intend to do, would probably be very hard later on.

You might want to look at:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes